# Playonlinux website wont load? - change DNS nameserver

Tags: dns, playonlinux

I'm using Chromium and i'm trying to download Playonlinux but the website wont load. Also should I download wine before I download Playonlinux?

EDIT: The problem is my current DNS nameserver. An `nslookup` with another nameserver (8.8.4.4) gave positive results. How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean http://www.playonlinux.com ? I can access it. Try again, maybe the server was just temporarily not available. And yes, you need wine, as playonlinux is just more or less a frontend to simplify handling wine.

---

ANSWER 2 - Setting a custom DNS nameserver:

Please follow those steps:

- `sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.backup` to create a backup of the DNS configuration file.
- `sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.default` to create another copy of the DNS configuration file.
- <del>`sudo sed /nameserver/s/\b69.89.215.3\b/8.8.4.4/g /etc/resolv.default`</del>
  `sudo nano /etc/resolv.default` **opens an editor. Replace the old nameserver addresses (69.89.215.3,...) with the line** `nameserver 8.8.4.4`.
  To save, press [Ctrl]+[o] and hit enter. Exit with [Ctrl]+[x].
- <del>`sudo echo "#!/bin/sh 
  cp /etc/resolv.default /etc/resolv.conf" > /etc/network/if-up.d/setnameserver.sh`</del>
  `sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/setnameserver.sh` **opens an editor on a new file. Please type the following:**

  `#!/bin/sh

  cp /etc/resolv.default /etc/resolv.conf`

  To save, press [Ctrl]+[o] and hit enter. Exit with [Ctrl]+[x].
  This is to create a bash script that automatically replaces the current config file with our prepared default-copy on every network startup.
- `sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/setnameserver.sh` to make the script executable.

Maybe you have to do a reboot or at least reconnect to your network. After this, try again to browse the playonlinux.com site or test it with `ping`, `traceroute` or `nslookup`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21029/discussion-on-answer-by-bytecommander-playonlinux-website-wont-load-change-dn).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to even visit the PlayOnLinux web site to install POL; it's in the Ubuntu default repositories.  Now, if you want a newer version than what Canonical considers "stable", that's another story.

No, you won't need to have Wine installed before installing POL, at least from the repos -- it'll pull in Wine 1.6 as a dependency, and can internally install ("manage") any other Wine version from (at least) 1.4 through current beta builds.  You can even change the Wine version serving an already-installed app (handy if you have an app that runs, but could be better; I went through half a dozen versions before finding one that would run There without crashing during login 5 times out of 6).